# apply_filters('the_content') - make it ignore shortcodes?

Tags: filters, content, wp-editor

I am using `apply_filters('the_content)` so I can see properly formatted content inside my wp  editor in the backend.

However, this also renders the shortcode that's in the content.

I want it to ignore the shortcode and apply filtering to the rest of the content, basically the same thing as when making posts. If you view post content in the backend, you will see the shortcode, but if you view it inside a page on your website, you will see the rendered shortcode (its result).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that parses the shortcode, `do_shortcode` is added as a filter on `the_content` by default, at priority 11.

You can remove it using [`remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter):

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
```

Call this right before you're actually using `the_content`, and add it afterwards (in the unlikely case that it's needed after that):

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
the_content():
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
```